# A question about Daily reputation limit

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

If I reach maximum reputation of $200$ a day and still get upvotes, will I get more of my reputation back the next day?

Answer (score 4):

[No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65546/214632).

(In some sense you didn't *lose* any rep: it just was never awarded.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/214632) for some of the reasoning behind the daily rep cap.)

Comment: I always wondered about the reasoning for the rep cap... Thanks for the link!