# 200 reputations limit per day

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Is the reputations obtained in one day over this limit can be reported for the next day?

If not, don't you think it might be a risk of loosing motivation answering after that very limit?

(Just asking :) )

Comment: No, those extra upvotes are lost forever. This is to cull statistical outliers, and is a widely accepted policy. Also consider that often a good answer nets only 3 upvotes or so. Sometimes less. Reaching the daily rep cap is sometimes a consequence of either answering an ultra popular question, or a user answering everything they can. The first of those reasons is built-in to the system, and can't really be cured (or, rather a cure would be worse than the disease). The latter is ok, and widely accepted, but something that  I personally disprove of.

Comment: If you are only motivated by upvotes, then I feel a bit sorry for you.

Comment: To make sure: My lack of sympathy for your cause is just my personal opinion. It is not a universally shared position (in spite of the diamond next to my name).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : thank you for you first answer :)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I don't have a cause, as I said, I'm just asking. Your second comment is way to categoric and (in my opinion) shadowed by your own beliefs ... in my beliefs. My question was just motivated by fairness (if you think money is bad, why accept small amont of it anyway?) and that the fact that reputations are useful for "bounties" as I understood, and for obtaining "privileges" (don't sure I like that name, but it's another question), i.e. having a chance to be more involved in the common life of the site... Feel free being sorry, but it would be truly an energy loss :)

Comment: You will receive the [bronze Mortarboard badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard) the first time you hit the daily reputation limit (which does not affect bonus awards and some other items).  See also the [silver Epic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic) and [gold Legendary](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary) badges for repeatedly hitting the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly this question has been asked [before](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13815/a-question-about-daily-reputation-limit) so here is the answer from [user642896](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8348/user642796) (in case the "before" button is inaccessible:

> [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65546/can-i-carry-over-my-points-over-the-rep-cap).
>
> (In some sense you didn't lose any rep: it just was never awarded. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap) for some of the reasoning behind the daily rep cap.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for he link, I didn't see that it was a duplicate, even though I looked a bit before.